# Are all the elements of order $2$ in a symmetric group reflections of some object with respect to some axis of reflection?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, reflection

> Are all the elements of order $2$ in a symmetric group reflections of some object with respect to some axis of reflection?

I know that reflections are of order $2.$ Is the converse true? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for some representation in which all the elements of order two are simultaneously reflections? I would also note that a half turn also has order $2$ as does the central inversion of the surface of a sphere.

Comment: Have a look at this other question, might be what you are looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123092/reflection-groups-and-symmetric-group

Comment: Yeah @Mark Bennet. You have rightly guessed.

Comment: @Mark Bennet I want to know whether there exists an element of order $2$ which is not a reflection?

Comment: The thread @user214962 found gives you a very good answer. Is there something else you want to know?

Comment: Difficulties in formulating an answer are A) what is *a reflection* for you? For me a reflection would be a mapping that keeps a codimension 1 subspace fixed and negates the vectors in its orthogonal complement, but that could also be called a simple reflection. Anyway, a reflection normally has no "axis" in higher dimensions. B) The answer may depend on how we are to map the permutations into symmetries of an object (which is the difficulty Mark Bennet described in different words). Are we free to choose the mapping also?